# How to disable USB Mass Storage in Mojave to free up device for libusb?

Tags: usb, mojave, kernel-extensions

I am trying to use usb_modeswitch via libusb to switch a Huawei HiLink USB LTE modem to Ethernet mode from mass storage mode. It fails with the following error.

> libusb: error [darwin_claim_interface] USBInterfaceOpen: another process has device opened for exclusive access

In previous macOS versions, an available solution was to unload the relevant kext, but `com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver` is now linked by `com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM` which is linked by `com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore`, and unloading the latter causes a kernel panic. (Ask me how I know.)

I am looking for another way to get the Mass Storage driver to let go of the device, so that it can be claimed by libusb. That can be both by disabling the driver, or by instructing it not to interact with this device.

There are similar questions like [How to disable USB Mass Storage Device in macOS Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350066/how-to-disable-usb-mass-storage-device-in-macos-mojave) which are looking for a way to stop USB storage from mounting, but that's not sufficient for my use case, if it does not enable libusb to claim the interface.

Comment: Relevant section of the libusb FAQ: https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_run_libusb_applications_under_Mac_OS_X_if_there_is_already_a_kernel_extension_installed_for_the_device

Comment: A codeless kext is likely to be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545656/codeless-kext-for-usb-storage-device

Comment: Interestingly, the original driver does not install any kext, but manages to modeswitch the modem, although it still gets initially mounted as mass storage.